# Best way to detect same files in php

Tags: php, md5

I have a web server, where users upload their files. I want to implement logic, that will show to user, if he will try to upload same file twice.

First idea is to save md5_file() value to the db and then check if there are any files with same md5 value. Files size differs from 2 megabytes up to 300.

1. I heared that md5 have collisions. Is this ok to use it?
2. Is it effective to use such logic with 300 megabytes files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly what hashing is for. Consider using [`sha1`](https://www.php.net/sha1), it's an all around superior hashing algorithm.

No, you probably shouldn't worry about collisions. The odds of people *accidentally* causing collisions is extremely low, close enough to impossible that you shouldn't waste any time thinking about it up-front. If you are seriously worried about it, use the hash as a first check, and then compare the file sizes, then compare the files bit-by-bit.

Comment: 2 differentt hash functions would satisfy any paranoic actually

Comment: @zerkms That means you have to generate and store two hashes for every single file, for the one-in-a-quadrillion-billion-million-zillion chance that you'll use it. It's better to compare bit-by-bit in that case, since it will *never happen anyways*.

Comment: @meagar so, you mean sha1_file? btw, if my files will be same, but their names will be different, this will not work, right?

Comment: To ensure even more uniqueness, you can tack on the UNIX TIMESTAMP. @trueツ But as Meagar stated, the chances of collision are slim.

Answer (score 1):

MD5 collisions are rare enough that in this case it shouldn't be an issue.

If you are dealing with large files however, you'll have to remember you are essentially uploading the file any way before you even check if it is a duplicate.

Upload -> MD5 -> Compare -> Keep or Disregard.

Answer (score 1):

If checking for duplicates, you can usually get away with using sha1.

Or to bulletproof it:

```
$hash = hash_file("sha512", $filename); // 128 char hex output
```

(And yes, with very large files md5 does indeed have a fairly high number of collisions)